# Remove an element from an array within a foreach loop *without* using $key = > $val

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-7

I'm working in PHP and I'm trying to loop through an array, and in certain circumstances, delete the particular element of the array.

I've seen multiple questions similar to this, but the answers always involve using `$key = $val` in the foreach.  I just have `&$element`. This is a relatively large loop, and switching to `$key => $value` would require a *lot* of rewrite and testing; so I'm hoping there's a way to do it with the referenced element.  (Basically there are a lot of different things that can happen depending on the value of the element. Removal is just one of many possibilities.)

Note that I *am* using $element by reference, not value.  I would swear this used to work, but it's not working now (maybe broke when I moved from PHP 5 to 7 ?)

So...

```
foreach( $things as &$element ) {
    ...
    if( $element == 'hello' ) {
        unset( $element );
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make this work using &$element ?

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: what format array is it initially?

Comment: When I run the code, the element is still there in the end.

Comment: The array is numerically indexed. Each element is an array (not that I think that would matter for the question....)  So the specific keys at the top level are unimportant to me

Comment: `foreach ($things as $key => &$element)` not work for you?

Comment: @CrayonViolent That's it! I was trying the $key=>$val without the reference!  Duh. Make it an answer and I'll tag it.

Comment: When you `unset( $element );`, you're unsetting the reference, not the actual referred item. I don't believe that's changed from PHP 5 to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$value` is just the variable you assign the value to; is arbitrary name. So you can use `$key=>$value` and your `&$element` reference together.

`foreach ($things as $key => &$element) { /* .. */ }`

Comment: And then `unset( $things[$key] );` does the job.  All the other code in the loop works the same as before, using $element.